# CLEARTEXT communication not permitted by network security policy working on my mobile

Tags: android, http, android-security, cleartext

I am building an APP, and facing CLEARTEXT communication not permitted by network security policy error on my friend mobile (I am just testing it on anther mobile). of course i am not able to trace the problem as the application is working OK on my mobile (without USB debugging), I download it from google play.

I did all needed to resolve this problem by adding 
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`
also I added  `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

my config XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
      <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">MY IP</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Its still not working.
I cannot trace the problem on my mobile because its working. Why i am not getting the same error as my friend mobile???

I want it to give me same error on my mobile to be able to trace the problem. I removed all the above options and it still working on my mobile. It was even working before I added any thing as I only discovered the problem after Installed on my friend mobile.

Comment: If you problem solved, then please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 127):

If you use http instead of https in your url, add this line to AndroidManifest.xml in the <application> tag.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: ok, but whats the point of introducing such a feature by google except complicate dev life

Comment: Any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: worked. Thanks. Can you explain the logic behind this? What is the actual issue?

Comment: I can also happen if you use `https://` but the server redirects your request to `http://`

Comment: this was part of the solution. In my case I also needed to change `localhost` to `10.0.2.2` in the base url.

Comment: it resolves my question, tks

Comment: For me it did not work

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem with react-native project. I get resolved the issue with this [article](http://www.douevencode.com/articles/2018-07/cleartext-communication-not-permitted/), putting **the domain name of my hosting provider**.

- Create `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` with content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my-domain-name.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

- Point to this file from your manifest (for bonus points add it only for the `test` manifest):

```xml
<application
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name=" (...)
</application>
```

Answer (score 4):

work for me! If you use Http instead of Https in your api url, then
just add   => android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  in AndroidManifest.xml in  tag.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:targetApi="31"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: Isn't this circumventing security policy of Android?

Answer (score 0):

**android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**

just put this line in your **Androidmanifest.xml** in **<application** tag