# How to show image in 'ScrollableTabRow'

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to build a `ScrollableTabRow` that include `text` and `image`.
:
[image: scrollable tab row with image](this screen shot was taken on compose 1.0.0-alpha09)

but after I upgrade compose to 1.0.0, the image didn't show. the image tab item is empty:

[image: scrollable tab row can't display image]

the `ScrollableTabRow` demo code:

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableRowWithImage(){
    ScrollableTabRow(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        selectedTabIndex = 0,
        edgePadding = 24.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.CenterStart)
    ) {
        (1..4).forEach{ _ ->
            Tab(
                selected = false,
                onClick = { },
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = rememberImagePainter(
                        data = "http://mstphoto.cmvideo.cn:8080/clt/20210607/09/1F7I2L5NT7HQ.png",
                    ),
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image can display normally in ohter place:

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableRowWithImage(){
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        ScrollableTabRow(
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            selectedTabIndex = 0,
            edgePadding = 24.dp,
            modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp)){
            (1..4).forEach{ _ ->
                Tab(
                    selected = false,
                    onClick = { },
                ) {
                    SampleImage()
                }
            }
        }
        Divider()
        SampleImage()
    }

}

@Composable
fun SampleImage(){
    Image(
        painter = rememberImagePainter(
            data = "http://mstphoto.cmvideo.cn:8080/clt/20210607/09/1F7I2L5NT7HQ.png",
        ),
        contentDescription = null,
    )
}
```

[image: image display normally in other place]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out state of your request to see if there's an error using `state` value:

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter("http://mstphoto.cmvideo.cn:8080/clt/20210607/09/1F7I2L5NT7HQ.png")
println("${painter.state}")
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp)
)
```

In your case it's:

> CLEARTEXT communication to mstphoto.cmvideo.cn not permitted by network security policy

Which is because you're using `http` instead of `https`, check out how to solve this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477085/3585796)

---

An other problem is with `Image` inside `ScrollableTabRow`. Looks like a coil bug, I've [reported](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/862). Image doesn't start loading without size modifier. Adding `.size(40.dp)` or even `.weight(40.dp)` solves the problem

Comment: thanks for reply，I've fixed the CLEARTEXT  problem,and this image can display normally on ohter place. but can not display in `ScrollableTabRow`

Comment: @TangSir and created a compose issue: https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/862

Answer (score 0):

Check it with a drawable resource, see if the problem is with the fetching of the data from the web. Replace the
`painter = rememberImagePainter( data = "http://mstphoto.cmvideo.cn:8080/clt/20210607/09/1F7I2L5NT7HQ.png", )`

with
`painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground) // OR any other resource, if this is not available`

Check if this resource renders and if it does not, I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Thanks for replay. after  Replace the `painter = rememberImagePainter( data = "http://mstphoto.cmvideo.cn:8080/clt/20210607/09/1F7I2L5NT7HQ.png", )`

with `painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)` . The resource display normally.